# react navigation drawer sidebar section

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

in this im trying to make a sidebar for the tablet UI and i wan to try so that if the

Drawer.Screen name = 'A'

the sidebar going to show but if change screen the sidebar did not show on their screen

here is the code of the Routes

```
const RoutesTablet = () => {


return (
    <Div row flex={1}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor={COLOR_PRIMARY} />
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="A"
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: COLOR_PRIMARY,
            // height: heightPercentageToDP(8),
          },
        }}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="A"
          component={Dashboard}
          options={{
            headerTitle: "Bob",
            headerRight: () => (
              <Image
                source={require("..........")}
                w={widthPercentageToDP(25)}
                h={heightPercentageToDP(4)}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen name="B" component={Sales} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
      <SideBar />
    </Div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to keep track of the state of `NavigationContainer` ([link to doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container)) and update the current screen name. We only render `SideBar` if the current screen name is `'A'`.

### Demo

[image]

### Source code

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

const A = () => <View />;
const B = () => <View />;

const SideBar = () => (
  <View
    style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
      right: 0,
      top: '25%',
      width: '10%',
      height: '50%',
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    }}>
    {'sidebar'.split('').map(text => (
      <View key={text} style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    ))}
  </View>
);

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const [curScreen, setCurScreen] = React.useState('A');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Use this to constantly listen to the current state of
    // NavigationContainer and update curScreen
    const unsubscribe = ref.current.addListener('state', e => {
      const lastHist = e.data.state.history.slice(-1)[0];
      if (lastHist.type === 'drawer') {
        setCurScreen('drawer');
      } else {
        setCurScreen(ref.current.getCurrentRoute().name);
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  });

  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={ref}>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="A">
        <Drawer.Screen name="A" component={A} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="B" component={B} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
      {curScreen === 'A' && <SideBar />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: the thing that you are given to me are working but it's in the mobile screen, but right know i work it on tablet, i can't use the position: 'absolute' because the UI i trying to make is POS style. thank you, its work but i need to make it into a row one

Comment: The code is just for demo purpose. The heart of the solution is to use `useState` to keep track of the current route of `NavigationContainer`. Once you have access to the current route, you can customize what to render and what not to render depending on the screen.